# Windows 10 hangs and SATA SSD (temporarily) disappears from BIOS

Tags: windows-10, ssd, freeze, sata

I have a system dual booting Linux and Windows 10. After about 10-15 minutes of using Windows 10 the system hangs (no BSOD, just a completely unresponsive desktop.) After a soft reboot, the main SSD (/dev/sda) is missing from BIOS, and the system can't be booted. After a hard reboot (turn off the system completely and restart) the drive is visible in BIOS again and bootable.

If I boot to Linux, I don't have any problem. I can use the system for hours without issue. This makes it look to me like a Windows problem, not hardware.

The Windows and Linux system partitions are both on the main drive (i.e. the one that's the problem.)

To be sure I did replace the SATA cable and tried to plug the drive into a different SATA port, but it had no effect.

Comment: Do you have latest firmware on the SSD?

Comment: Yes, just double checked, it's up to date. FWIW, it's a Samsung 840 EVO 250G, firmware version EXT0AB0Q.

Comment: It could be a bad or loose sata cable.

Comment: Like I said, I replaced the cable. Also doesn't explain why the issue only occurs under Windows, but not under Linux.

Comment: Maybe your SSD has some problem with the hardware that only happens when certain locations are accessed, and some Windows file is at that location.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Maralc Yes in the end I just swapped the main drive with a secondary one and then everything was fine. The drive itself never showed any errors after that. I have to imagine it's some weird driver issue in Windows. Sorry not a very good solution but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my "solution" was to swap out the system drive with another SSD I had.  The drive that was causing the problems was swapped to be a secondary drive in the computer. After that everything worked fine.

Not really a proper solution but this is how I ended up.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues, with the same drive (Samsung EVO 840 250G) a year or two back where a computer would blue screen all the time, at irregular intervals.
Did the normal firmware/drivers checks etc, but nothing worked.

When doing checks on the drive on another computer, everything looked ok, but suddenly it just vanished, and after restart of computer it was back.
It was very irregular how it vanished and I couldn't find a pattern, other than writing/reading data to it. Something hardware related I assume.

So, probably when the drive disappeared, Windows couldn't access OS-files and blue screened.

Replaced the SSD with an new one, and installed a fresh windows, and the computer never had any freezes after that.